# Sqoop error when trying to connect

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

I am trying to run the following Sqoop command:

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sunil_sqoop --table sqoop_emp --username root  --password 225dvrdlr)
```

However, I am getting this error:

> 17/02/04 00:04:53 WARN security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:avinash (auth:SIMPLE) cause:java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://localhost:9000/home/avinash/sqoop-1.4.6.bin__hadoop-2.0.4-alpha/lib/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar
>   17/02/04 00:04:53 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Encountered IOException running import job: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://localhost:9000/home/avinash/sqoop-1.4.6.bin__hadoop-2.0.4-alpha/lib/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$17.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1093)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$17.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1085)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1085)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.getFileStatus(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:288)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.getFileStatus(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:224)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.determineTimestamps(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:93)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.determineTimestampsAndCacheVisibilities(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:57)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.copyAndConfigureFiles(JobSubmitter.java:267)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.copyAndConfigureFiles(JobSubmitter.java:388)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:481)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1295)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1292)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1642)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1292)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1313)
>       at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.doSubmitJob(ImportJobBase.java:196)
>       at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.runJob(ImportJobBase.java:169)
>       at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.runImport(ImportJobBase.java:266)
>       at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.importTable(SqlManager.java:673)
>       at org.apache.sqoop.manager.MySQLManager.importTable(MySQLManager.java:118)
>       at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:497)
>       at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:605)
>       at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:143)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
>       at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:179)
>       at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:218)
>       at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:227)
>       at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:236)

What should I do.

Answer (score 0):

Error:

```
File does not exist: hdfs://localhost:9000/home/avinash/sqoop-1.4.6.bin__hadoop-2.0.4-alpha/lib/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar
```

You should copy file slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar to directory in HDFS:

```
home/avinash/sqoop-1.4.6.bin__hadoop-2.0.4-alpha/lib/.
```

Or you can copy this jar to Oozie sharelib.